# How to remove image script if it has no image?

Tags: views

I created a block using views.
The fields has image, title and body.

While the article has no image, it still render out the image script and it make a space before the title.

How do it make the image script disappear if there is no article in its.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Image field configuration**:

Click on **No results behavior** section.

You will get the option to hide.

[image]